# LyX how to reproduce a label

Tags: lyx, labels

What can I do in LyX to to reproduce (borders included)
[image]

you can find a source file (.odt) for the label at address https://mega.co.nz/#F!x1Bx1QaB!wVg-o2BV_RX97PveXMpBGA

Comment: Any article class will do, nothing special. some centering, some tabular. I bet, if you provide the text in form of a minimal working example, a nice person will do the formatting.

Comment: @Johannes_B added to the original message :-)

Comment: @Caterpillar Not quite a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), what you've posted.

Comment: @yo'just edited the question, saying that I use LyX and then I cannot provide a working example

Comment: [This meta answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/4490/) explains that you ***can*** add an MWE, and explains how to do so if using LyX. If you really couldn't produce MWEs because using LyX, I'd say that would be a compelling reason to find an alternative editor - at least when working on projects you might need help with. I say this because you obviously wouldn't expect people to type the contents of your documents from scratch on a site like this. (It would be different, of course, if you were hiring somebody to produce the image. That is always another option.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No comments. See other posts here to see how to import the code in LyX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp,mdframed,lmodern}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{mdframed}[%
                 innerleftmargin=1pt,%
                 innerrightmargin=1pt,%
                 innertopmargin=1pt,%
                 innerbottommargin=1pt]
\sffamily
{
\centering
\emph{\textbf{Farmacia Solefiorito Dottoressa A. Nutria}}

Via dei soli, 30-32 00910 -- Milano

{\large Tel. 02123456789 Fax 0123456789\par}

\bigskip

N\textdegree\dots\dots\hspace*{.5cm}
Data 15.01.2015\hspace*{2cm}
Data scad. 15.04.2015

\medskip

Dott. \dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\hfill Paziente \dots\dots\dots\dots\dots
}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{@{}p{8cm}ll}
Clorazepato dipotassico g 0.003 & Sostanze                   & \dots\dots\dots\\
Eccipiente B g 0.197            & Onorario                   & \dots\dots\dots\\
                                & Dir. Add.                  & \dots\dots\dots\\
Capsule n.100                   & Recipiente                 & \dots\dots\dots\\
                                & \textbf{Totale. \texteuro} & \dots\dots\dots\\
\end{tabular}

\medskip

Avvertenze: Soggetto a legge 49/2006 Tab. II B. USO INTERNO

Precauzioni: Tenere fuori dalla portata dei bambini. Non disperdere il flacone nell'ambiente.

Posologia: Secondo prescrizione.
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]